# How do I retrieve a site using notions api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, notion-api

I am currently trying to download a site/page using notions API.
I shared the page and tried this:

```
(async () => {

    const pageId = 'abcd-editorial-efe.notion.site/Sites-abc123';
  
    const response = await notion.pages.retrieve({ page_id: pageId });
  
    console.log(response);
  
  })();
```

I get an error saying:

```
@notionhq/client warn: request fail {
  code: 'object_not_found',
  message: 'Could not find page with ID: abc123..... Make sure the relevant pages and databases are shared with your integration.'
}
```

Is this the correct API endpoint to retrieve a page?

Notions docs pageId is a GUID...but when I shared my page I get a complete/full URL:

```
(async () => {

  const pageId = 'b55c9c91-384d-452b-81db-d1ef79372b75';

  const response = await notion.pages.retrieve({ page_id: pageId });

  console.log(response);

})();
```

I am using  `"@notionhq/client": "^1.0.4"`

Comment: Are you sure you have invited the integration to the page itself? Creating the integration is not enough.

Comment: @MuhammadMagdi I just shared the page to public... not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

## Before Nov 2022

You used to have to invite integrations like [Muhammad Magdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396153/how-do-i-retrieve-a-site-using-notions-api#comment127974192_72396153) mentioned in the comments:

In the `share` section (top right), select `invite` and invite your integration.

## After Nov 2022

As stated by [umihico] below, in the latest version of Notion you 'Add connections' from the top-right "three dots" menu.

Comment: My API call doesn't work, yet the page is visible in super.so... how is that possible?  they are able to call my api

Comment: what is the uri of your call?

Comment: I pasted it above..i'm using the nodejs library

Comment: Today I had to use 'Add connections' from top right three dots menu. Non-human accounts such as integrations seems not being invited anymore

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a successful workspace connection but that you haven't granted that connection access to a database *within* your workspace.

To do this:

1. Click on the 3 dots in the top right.
2. Find "Add Connections" near the bottom.
3. Search for the name of your connection in the box.
4. Select and confirm your connection's access to the database.